# com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemo

Tags: android

[image: h]Upgraded to Android studio 3.4 - Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2: Daemon startup failed 5 and changing the gradle is not working

i have changed gradle 3.4.1 to 3.3.2 but not wrking

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Windows Universal C Runtime.